# help installing PyQt5. recieving error : 'DocumentTooLarge' is not a member of 'QJsonParseError'

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5

hi im quite new but have managed to install sip v4.16.9

```
(precise)cloud12321@localhost:~/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5$ sip -V 4.16.9
```

Now the configure.py went fine. the problem i have is that every time i try to make PyQt5 it gives me these errors:

```
cd QtCore/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/cloud12321/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5/QtCore/QtCore.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/cloud12321/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5/QtCore'
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQSize.o sipQtCoreQSize.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQFile.o sipQtCoreQFile.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQAbstractAnimation.o sipQtCoreQAbstractAnimation.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQTextEncoder.o sipQtCoreQTextEncoder.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQSortFilterProxyModel.o sipQtCoreQSortFilterProxyModel.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQWriteLocker.o sipQtCoreQWriteLocker.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQList0100QPersistentModelIndex.o sipQtCoreQList0100QPersistentModelIndex.cpp
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fno-exceptions -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DSIP_PROTECTED_IS_PUBLIC -Dprotected=public -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/share/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I../qpy/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -o sipQtCoreQJsonParseError.o sipQtCoreQJsonParseError.cpp
/home/cloud12321/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5/QtCore/sipQtCoreQJsonParseError.cpp:147:49: error: 'DocumentTooLarge' is not a member of 'QJsonParseError'
make[1]: *** [sipQtCoreQJsonParseError.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cloud12321/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5/QtCore'
make: *** [sub-QtCore-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on what needs to be one to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

SIP must be installed before building and using PyQt5. You can get the latest release of the SIP source code from [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download).

The SIP documentation can be found [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/).

You can get the latest release of the GPL version of the PyQt5 source code from [here](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5).

[For more informations](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html)

Comment: i already have SIP installed   (precise)cloud12321@localhost:~/Downloads/PyQt-gpl-5/PyQt-gpl-5.5$ sip -V
4.16.9  ..... so as you see its installed and i have been to the webpage specified in the bottom of your answer and it has nothing there about the two errors im getting

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I had Qt 5.0 installed, which comes regularly with Ubuntu 12.04.

To fix it I installed Qt 5.5 (for Ubuntu 12.04 see [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/657293/458895)) and then passed the corresponding qmake path to the configure.py script using the --qmake flag.